# ffmpeg not working from php script but works from command line

Tags: perl, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

i can run youtube-dl.php from  command line "php youtube-dl.php" works fine

but not working from http...
is it someting with chown?

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdS6HFQ_LUc";

echo "Saving $url";


$cmd = 'youtube-dl -o "/var/www/domain.com/test/%(title)s.%(ext)s" '.$url.' -f bestvideo+bestaudio'; 
exec($cmd, $output, $ret);
echo 'output: ';
var_export($output);
```

echo "\nret: ";
var_export($ret);

Comment: Pretty sure that's not perl. Or if it is, it's pretty bad perl. For starters - there's no `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to run any scripts in the first place. Simply add `-f bestvideo+bestaudio/best` to your youtube-dl command-line and let youtube-dl merge the video automatically. Don't forget to install ffmpeg!

Comment: thanks but i cant get ffmpeg to merge the video files when running it from apache...  is it something with chown?

Answer (score 0):

For downloading video in format of your choice type in following :

```
youtube-dl -F  {video URL}
```

When you type in the command for downloading video with format or your choice it'll give you list of different options, showing the formats and resolutions of that video.
choose the code of one you like and type in following:

```
youtube-dl -f  {format code} {video URL}
```

Comment: thanks but that does not work from php, it doesnt merge the files with ffmpeg nor does it auto grab the bestvid+au